# Setting an environment variable to a space in GDB

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb

I need to set an environment variable to a single space in GDB, but when I tried

```
set env VAR ' '
```

GDB actually sets VAR to the 3-character string, namely quote, space and then a quote. Is there a way to properly do this in GDB? Or is GDB simply parsing the arguments and setting varialbes to the strings passed as is (without escaping etc.)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not appear to be possible directly.  The in build documentation (`help set env`) states:

```
VALUES of environment variables are uninterpreted strings.
```

and GDB's source code (specifically `environ.c` and `infcmd.c`) concur with this and do not show any explicit manipulation of the value other than removing training whitespace.